# Are questions on augmented reality on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Should we answer questions pertaining to the implementation of augmented reality?

For example, I was thinking of posting something along the lines of:

I want to add an image to a printed piece that is meant to be scanned for augmented reality. How should I implement augmented reality if my original image is distorted by the surface to which it is printed? (e.g. an image printed on a curved surface like a bottle)

Comment: I have no idea what this question and discussion means? A bottle adding curvature what??

Comment: [Augmented Reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality) I think it should probably be in http://video.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Ryan In augmented reality, you scan an image with your phone (not unlike QR codes) and it becomes something else like a video for example but it could be an animation, another image, etc. But I do admit my question was much clearer in my head than on text, I'll edit it to make it clearer :-)

Comment: Oh okay, so you're putting something like a QR code or barcode on non-flat packaging for some kind of device to read and you want to check the device will still be able to read it? Your best bet would be to go wherever the experts on that device are - where that is depends on the device.

Comment: I think your question is on topic, but has nothing to do with Augmented Reality. All you seem to be asking about is how to Print a Barcode or QR code on a curved surface.

Comment: Another way to put it would be: is the curvature going to keep my AR from working and if so, how can I minimize the problems?. The thing with AR is that from what I understand, it doesn't have to be a square format like barcodes or QR codes.

Comment: Your most recent comment again leaves me confused. What do you think AR is Emilie?

Comment: I'm not talking about QR or barcodes, more specifically interactive print by scanning an image (e.g. photo or illustration, logo) that will animate, play a video, a sound on a smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the code to be printed and read is, and (possibly) what the device reading it is.

If it's just a QR code or barcode, there will probably be plenty of designers with experience of taking that into account in designs, so ask away. *But* focus on whichever of QR codes or barcodes it is, not what happens *after* the code is read. Your question seems to be, how to make sure the code is readable on a surface with X shape: how you print the code would be exactly the same if the thing the code triggers is showing an augmented reality display or loading a web page or setting the user's battery on fire etc etc.

If it's some other less common type of code and/or some very specific device, then you'd be better off asking the manufacturer or finding some specialist forum for that type of technology, simply because the chances of anyone having worked on that exact device are very low.

Answer (score 0):

To add to user568458's answer:

No based on what you've said I don't think your question is on topic because it has nothing to do with graphic design.

Take for example the Graphic Design Stack Exchange Logo. I could hire a team of developers to write an application that detects that pattern on digital images. If it detects it then X occurs. X could be anything as user568458 mentioned.

Your question is how would I print the GD.SE Logo onto a curved surface and still have it be detected. Thats a question for the team that develops the application. Its a matter of scale and precision. Just like an app that can read a barcode on a can or bottle.

These aren't graphic design questions.

I'm not saying there may not be an Augmented Reality question that does have a foundation in Graphic Design but the example you're providing does not.